# Golang imports issue

Tags: go, import

The problem is that  have `GOPATH` as "...user/go" and inside this directory i have folders `pkg` and `src`. So iam trying to install package from git by calling `go get` command, for example:

```
go get -u gorm.io/gorm
```

Then I import it in my project by calling

```
import "gorm.io/gorm"
```

But compiler search this package inside the `GOPATH/src` folder (not in `GOPATH/pkg/mod`, where this package is installed). How can I fix it? Can I, for example, change default folder where compiler should search for packages or do smth else?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olngg.png)

This is the "go env" command output:

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\danny\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\danny\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\danny\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\danny\go\src\mirea-scheduler-api\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments - 
fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Temp\go- 
build3986247088=/tmp/go-build -gno-re
cord-gcc-switches
```

Comment: Maxim can you please share the output of `go env` when executed inside your project's directory?

Comment: @mkopriva This is it:
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\danny\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\danny\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\danny\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16.3

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: @Maxim can you please edit the question and add the `go env` output there, it's hard to read in the comment.

Comment: @mkopriva Sure, sorry! Already added.

Comment: @Maxim ok I see that you've already added a `go.mod` file to your project (`C:\Users\danny\go\src\mirea-scheduler-api\go.mod`), is the import still failing, still with the same error? If so, can you share the contents of your `go.mod` file (by updating the question again)?

Comment: @Maxim have you tried compiling the program directly using `go build`? I wonder if the problem isn't caused by a misconfiguration in the IDE, rather than the project itself.

Comment: @mkopriva I think, I fixed it! I added value for GOMODCACHE inside goland IDE and now it works)) Should i add it to question body and close it?

Comment: @Maxim yes you can close the question, or if you think the information might be useful to others you can also post an answer and then later accept it.

Answer (score 1):

So, the thing that helped me was to add GOMODPATH with path, where modules are stored (in my case it is "..user/go/pkg/mod") inside Goland IDE:
[image]